# The font size is getting reduced throughout the document - LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm creating my resume using a latex template on Overleaf. Everything was ok, but I just realized the font size is reducing throughout the document and I don't know why.

This is the configuration at the beginning of the code:

`\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{altacv}`

And this is what happens:

[Lorem ipsum text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMEXH.png)

As you can see, the font size in the first paragraph (which is in the first page) is bigger than the second page one. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Please post the relevant code (reduce he content so that it is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Check this thread , it will help you [how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt)